# string matching in C without using any predefined function?

Tags: c, string

Here is my code. I am matching the string with the help of loops. I don't want to use any function for it.

```
  int main()
  {
      int flag,j;
      char a[30]={'\0'};
      char b[]="this is a dog";

      printf("enter string \n");
      gets(a);

      int p = strlen(b);

     for(j=0;j<p;j++)
     {
         if(a[j]==b[j])
         {
             flag=0;
         }
         else
             flag=1;
         break;
     }
        if(flag==0)
           printf("yes");
        else
           printf("no");

    return 0;
  }
```

The problem is that it is checking a string in wrong way.
Like "this is a dog" and "this is a man" are equal for it.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. It's like posting "Trees are green".

Comment: You need to check for the terminator of the string you input. What if string `a` is smaller than string `b`?

Comment: break is for for loop buddy..

Comment: there is no need to use strlen() instead just loop until you find the terminating \0

Comment: actually problem is that it is checking a string in wrong way..like

Comment: like "this is a dog" and "this is a man" are equal for it.

Comment: Read my answer and implement that in your code and see the result.

Comment: thanks hacks..thanks others too..

Comment: This question belongs on programmers site on Stack Exchange Network.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `break` statement is out of `else` and this causes your loop to break after first iteration. You need this

```
else
{
     flag=1;
     break;
}
```

Comment: Even tho there are better ways to solve the problem than the approach from the question itself, I guess this one actually answers the question. (Since I guess he just wanted to know what he was doing wrong..)

Answer (score 2):

You're using strlen. you don't need that.

C strings should be matched until one of the strings have a `'\0'` or one of the characters is different.

```
char* pa = a;
char* pb = b;
while (*pa != *pb && *pa && *pb) {
    ++pa; ++pb;
}

// a equals b if (*pa == *pb) == true
// BTW, in equality they will both be zero which is the stop condition for the loop

printf("strings are %s", (*pa == *pb) ? "equal" : "different");
```

Comment: If it is homework, which I assume it is, then he can't use strlen :)

Comment: i use strlen because  iam developing it as a habit..as i forgot many times how to get length in C..after using java and other languages..well its not a homework...

Answer (score 1):

This here looks like you forgot a } -- it is good to do proper indentation

```
for(j=0;j<p;j++)
{
  if(a[j]==b[j])
  {
     flag=0;
  }
  else
    flag=1;
  break;
}
```

the break will make your loop quit at the first iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this without `strlen` ( a predefined function ):

```
 int main(){
  int flag=0,j,i=0;
  char b[]="this is a dog\0";
  printf("enter string \n");

  char input[50]; // change the size to compensate for your biggest input

  char get; // variable to collect input character one by one

  get = getchar(); // get the first character

  while(get!='\n'){ // I am assuming \n marks the end of input
     input[i] = get; // put that character into the input array
     i++;            // incriment counter ( replaces strlen as it counts how much is read )
     get = getchar(); // get the next character
  }


     for(j=0;j<i;j++){
        if(input[j]==b[j]){
          // do nothing .. keep looping to see if other characters are the same too
        }else{
         flag=1;  // the very first character that is different  .. break from loop and print not same
         break;
        }
     }   

     if(flag==0){
        printf("yes\n");
     }else{
        printf("no\n");

     }

   return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like:

```
for(j=0;j<p;j++)
 {
     if(a[j]==b[j])
     {
         flag=0;
     }
     else 
     {
         flag=1;
         break;
     }
 }

if(flag==0)
       printf("yes");
else
       printf("no");
```

Comment: no point setting flag to 0 every time you loop with same charaters